# "Uploaded a Debuggable APK" to Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am trying to upload the latest version bundle of an app that is already in the Google Play Console and I received this message:

> You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle.

I have not defined `android:debuggable` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

If I try to define `android:debuggable = "false"` I get an error telling me that I should avoid hardcoding the debug mode as the system now assigns that as required.

How can I please both Android Studio and Google Play Console in their seemingly mixed messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @basilisk led me towards the solution by referring to the `build.gradle` file where `debuggable true` had been set for me. I changed this to `debuggable false` and the Console would now accept my app bundle without any warnings.

So in short check if `debuggable` is set in `build.gradle` as well as in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: There was no need to assign `debuggable` status in `AndroidManifest.xml` at the first place, the best practice is to set `debuggable` in your app `build.gradle` file and according to your buld variants.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are uploading the debug variant of the app instead of the release one. Since the app you are uploading already has a previous version on Google Play, you will need to upload a release variant signed with the same key as the previous one.

Check if you have the following in your app level build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("...")
        storePassword "..."
        keyAlias "..."
        keyPassword "..."
    }
}
```

If it does, you can build the release variant by the command

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

If your build.gradle does not have the release signing config, then it must have been signed using Android Studio's "Generate Signed Build" option, and you will have to get the keystore file from the person who generated it in the first place.

You can read more about app signing [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: Thanks @basilisk . I am indeed specifying the `signingConfigs` in my `build.gradle`. Your answer draw my eye to the `debuggable true` in the buildTypes for the release in the gradle file. I have set that to false and will try uploading the new bundle.